# Updating text in component drawn in drawRect in UIView subclass

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect

I have a UIView with it's subclass set in interface builder to a UIView subclass I created. I want to update labels within the UIView class holding them. I cannot seem to update the text of any labels drawn in drawRect. What are my options for drawing elements I need to change within a UIView subclass?

```
// Using UILabel subclass (FontLabel)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    scoreLabel = [[FontLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 400, 50) fontName:@"Intellect" pointSize:80.0f];
    scoreLabel.textColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.8157 green:0.8000 blue:0.0706 alpha:1.0f];

    [scoreLabel sizeToFit];
    [scoreLabel setText:@"Initial text"];
    [self addSubview:scoreLabel];

    [self setNeedsDisplay]; 
    //Also tried [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)updateScoreLabel:(int)val 
{
    [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", val]];
}   



// Using CATextLayer

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    scoreLabel = [CATextLayer layer];
    [scoreLabel setForegroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [scoreLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 20)];
    [scoreLabel setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
    [[self layer] addSublayer:scoreLabel];
    [scoreLabel setString:@"Initial text"];


    [self setNeedsDisplay]; 
    //Also tried [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)updateScoreLabel:(int)val 
{
    [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", val]];
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to update the text programmatically, or in IB?

Comment: Programmatically. It's worth noting I also tried this with CATextLayer and didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the text of labels programmatically, you need to do the following:

In your .h file:

- Define them as `UILabel`s in your @interface section
- Add `IBOutlet`s to them in your @property declarations

In your .m file:

- Put in @synthesize lines for them in your .m file.

After that, you can refer to them as any other `self.` variable, and set their `text` property to change how they appear in your display.

In general, trying to subclass `UIView` can be a bit tricky (as you're finding), but hopefully the above will help you at least a bit.

Comment: The variables are class variables. I did not add an outlet as the objects are not built in IB.

Comment: I accessed the variables using self. and I am still left with text which refuses to change.

Comment: Aha, so you're creating the labels programmatically as well.  I haven't done that before, so I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @Kyle Humfeld So, I've following all your steps in the end, I've tried eithr [imageWithCaptionView.label setText:@"testBALBALBAL"]; 
 or imageWithCaptionView.label.text = @"testBALBALBAL";  followed by [imageWithCaptionView setNeedsDisplay]; but it doesn't work. Any tip ? thanks